# How to create custom folder in Shared Queries TFS?

Tags: powershell, tfs, tfs-2015

I'm trying to create a folder inside "Shared Queries" TFS work item folder via POSH.

```
$teamProjectCollection = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory]::GetTeamProjectCollection($ProjectCollectionUri);
        #Get Work Item Store object
        $wiStore = $teamProjectCollection.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore])
        $teamProject = $wiStore.Projects["$ProjectName"]
```

$teamProject returned is null. I can enumerate all other projects but not the one which I specified as parameter.
Any clue what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if the project name you specified is existed in the team project collection and make sure you have the permission to access to it.

To create a folder under "Shared Queries" folder, refer to following code for details:

```
$pathToAss4 = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v4.5"
Add-Type -Path "$pathToAss2\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$pathToAss2\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "$pathToAss4\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.ProjectManagement.dll";

$projectname = "ProjectName"
$CollectionUrl = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/tfs/defaultcollection"
$tfs = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory]::GetTeamProjectCollection($CollectionUrl)
$ws = $tfs.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore])
$teamProject = $ws.Projects["$projectname"]
$addfoldername = "NewFolder"
$addfolder = new-object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.QueryFolder -ArgumentList "$addfoldername"
$queryhi = $teamProject.QueryHierarchy
$parentfolder = $queryhi["Shared Queries"]
$parentfolder.Add($addfolder)
$teamProject.QueryHierarchy.Save()
```